# JSONP Parse Error with valid JSON Output

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, ajax, jsonp

I am calling a Cross Domain AJAX Request using JSONP. Now, i am able to make it work using CORS. But, i want to know why it is not happening with JSONP. I looked at other threads with similar problem but couldnt figure out why it is not working in my case.

Here is the code:

```
 $.ajax({
        type: "GET",
        url: http://XXXX:8000/sap/bc/test_rest/jsonp_test?mode=S&ticket=123,
        dataType: "jsonp",
        jsonp: false,
        jsonpCallback: "myJsonMethod",
        success: function (data) {
            alert(data);
        },
        error: function (httpReq, status, exception) {
            alert(status + " " + exception);
        }
    });
```

Now, this calls my server, the data is populated and then i get an alert "**parse error** myJSONMethod was not called" on a callback URL http://xxxx:8000/sap/bc/test_rest/jsonp_test?mode=S&ticket=123&_=1470322282936

Additionally, in the console i get the error as **Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token :**
The response structure is:

```
{"ROOT":{"CONTRACT":"40002356","ITEM":"000010","KUNNR":"0000004676","NAME":"REALTY EXECUTIVES","NET_PRICE":19.95,"GROSS_PRICE":19.95,"MATNR":"144","SQFEET":""}}
```

When i run this JSON Output on jsonlint it says it is a valid JSON. I don't know where the JSON is getting messed up.

Comment: Can you share the `myJsonMethod` code?

Comment: you need to wrap your json in myJsonMethod(...yourJSONhere...). That means JSONP

Comment: Valid JSON is not the same thing as valid JSONP. That's the problem - you're trying to use an API that returns JSON as if it were a JSONP API, and that simply will not work.

Comment: Thanks Guys!!! If the server doesn't automatically provide JSONP support, force wrap it and it works :D

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your data must be like this to be valid for JSONP:

```
myJsonMethod({"ROOT":{"CONTRACT":"40002356","ITEM":"000010","KUNNR":"0000004676","NAME":"REALTY EXECUTIVES","NET_PRICE":19.95,"GROSS_PRICE":19.95,"MATNR":"144","SQFEET":""}});
```

Comment: Thank You very much. I had to manually wrap it on the Server Side to make it look like that and it worked perfectly.

Answer (score 1):

the responsetext must be valid js code and it will run immediately when the response is over.So if you write your code

> {"ROOT":{"CONTRACT":"40002356","ITEM":"000010","KUNNR":"0000004676","NAME":"REALTY
>   EXECUTIVES","NET_PRICE":19.95,"GROSS_PRICE":19.95,"MATNR":"144","SQFEET":""}}

in a `<script>` tag,the console will throw an err like that